# Creating a candlestickgraph in android

Tags: android, stocks

I was looking at stockcharts - http://code.google.com/p/stock-chart for creating candlestickgraphs in my application. I could not find any good tutorials on it. Does anyone know of some good tutorial for using stock charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try afree chart api for candlestickgraphs. It contains all types of charts. The following link contains sample code

[afreechart](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/source/browse/trunk/)

and try this link too

[Candlestickgraphs in JFreeChart](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartCandlestickDemo.htm)